# How to serve private contents to only authenticated users?

Tags: android, security, http, authentication

Sorry if I am asking a trivial question...

I have been writing a HTTP server for my Android application. Currently I am using Netty for my server.

Here's my configuration for my server.

1. Client sends a request with ID and Password to log in.
2. Then the server responses with specific userNumber assigned to each ID.
3. The client can get whatever he wants(images, profile info ...) with this user number.

However, here's my big problem.

Anyone(even users that did not log in) can get access to my server contents if he has the right request method(POST), right user number(which is a static number for each ID).

Stupidly I thought SSL could somehow magically authenticate users. Now I know that it does not authenticate but rather secure the messages being transfered.

> In short, what are some methods that can block unauthenticated users? Should the client always send ID, Password(stored in local when login) for each request to prove that it is a valid user?

Comment: why don't you send the login/password for each request ?

Comment: @njzk2 I thought the most secure server would send less confidential information to reduce the damage of the attacks.

Comment: true. you can generate temporary tokens and use these for connexion. I usually tend to avoid complex sessions management, for scaling reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store Username & Password in shared preferences & 
prepare a HTTP request with values stored in shared preferences.

Steps

1. Store User's login credentials in shared preferences
2. Get the url of HTTP request.
3. Prepare a new url with Login credentials from shared preferences
4. Either you can send Login credentials or can generate a temporary access token for this client
5. Send the appropriate access token with HTTP url
6. access token will destroy when user logs out

Comment: Thank you for answering Kailash! One of my friends suggest using oAuth. After reading a little about it, it seems like oAuth works somewhat like the steps you provided. Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Yeah, it's same as oAuth. oAuth is more secured way & above solution is simple way of doing on your server. You can go without oAuth with the above method but i think you should go with oAuth.